# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16d0f3ff0)

Tags: ios, swift4.2

I am developing an app (in `XCode` Version 11.2 and Swift 4.2) in which I fill in a LinkedList and after working with it, removing the elements that compose it produces the `Thread 1 error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 2, address = 0x16d0f3ff0)`. The error occurs even without working with the items in the list, simply by adding them and trying to eliminate them the error already occurs. The tests I am doing with an iPhone with `IOS version 11.4.1`

The implementation of the LinkedList is as follows:

```
import Foundation

public class Node<T> {

    var value: T
    var next: Node<T>?
    weak var previous: Node<T>?

    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    } // init
} // Node

public class LinkedList<T> {

    private var head: Node<T>?

    private var tail: Node<T>?

    public private(set) var count: Int = 0

    public init() { } // init

    public var isEmpty: Bool {
        return  self.head == nil
    } // isEmpty

    public var first: Node<T>? {
        return  self.head
    } // first

    public var last: Node<T>? {
        return  self.tail
    } // last

    public func nodeAt(index: Int) -> Node<T>? {
        if index >= 0 {
            var node =  self.head
            var i = index
            while node != nil {
                if i == 0 {
                    return node
                } // if

                i -= 1
                node = node!.next
            } // while
        } // if

        return nil
    } // nodeAt

    public func removeAll() {
        self.head = nil
        self.tail = nil

        self.count = 0
    } // removeAll

    public func remove(node: Node<T>?) -> String {
        if isEmpty {
            return String("ERROR: Empty list, nothing to remove.")
        } // if

        guard node != nil else {
           return String("ERROR: Invalid node, nothing to remove.")
        } // guard

        let prev = node?.previous
        let next = node?.next

        if next != nil && prev == nil {
            self.head = next
            next?.previous = nil
        } else if next != nil && prev != nil {
            prev?.next = next
            next?.previous = prev
        } else if next == nil && prev != nil {
             self.tail = prev
            prev?.next = nil
        } // if
        node?.previous = nil
        node?.next = nil

        self.count -= 1
        return String("Successfully removed node: \(node!.value)")
    } // remove

    func enqueue(value: T) {
        let newNode = Node(value: value)

        if let tailNode =  self.tail {
               newNode.previous = tailNode
               tailNode.next = newNode
        } else {
                self.head = newNode
        } // else
        self.tail = newNode
        self.count += 1
    }

    func enqueue_first(value: HexRecord) {
        let newNode = Node(value: value)

        if let headNode = self.head {
            newNode.next = headNode
            headNode.previous = newNode
        } 
        self.head = newNode
        self.count += 1
    }

    func dequeue() -> T? {
        let element =  self.head?.value
        self.head =  self.head?.next
        self.count -= 1

        return element
    }

} // LinkedList
```

The nodes of the same are of the HexRecord type:

```
public class HexRecord
{
    private var length: Int = 0
    private var address: Int64 = 0
    private var type: Int32 = 0
    private var data = [UInt8] ()
    private var checksum: UInt8 = 0

    init()
    {

    }

    public func getAddress() -> Int64 {
        return address;
    }

    public func getType() -> Int32 {
        return type;
    }

    public func getData() -> [UInt8] {
        return data;
    }

    public func getLength() -> Int {
        return length;
    }

    public func getChecksum() -> UInt8 {
        return checksum;
    }


    public func setAddress(address: Int64) {
        self.address = address;
    }

    public func setData(data: [UInt8]) {
        self.data = data;
    }

    public func setLength(length: Int) {
        self.length = length;
    }

    public func setType(type: Int32) {
        self.type = type;
    }

    public func setChecksum(checksum: UInt8) {
        self.checksum = checksum;
    }
}
```

It is used as follows:

```
func tratar_registros() {

    var records = LinkedList<HexRecord>();

    ....

    let data_line: HexRecord? = try parseRecord(line: line)  // parseRecord convert String to HexRecord
    if (data_line != nil)
    {
        records.enqueue(value: data_line!)
    }
    ....

    records.removeAll();        //Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16d0f3ff0)

} // Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16d0f3ff0)     if there is no line records.removeAll();
```

With the debugger I see that the error occurs when assigning the value nil to self.head. Just before self.head has correct values, it becomes nil and the error is skipped before reaching the next instruction (within the removeAll function)

In the Debug Navigator, in the stackTrace the last 2 functions where the error is seen:

```
libobjc.A.dylib`_object_remove_assocations:
    0x180d11eec <+0>:   sub    sp, sp, #0x70             ; =0x70 
->  0x180d11ef0 <+4>:   stp    x26, x25, [sp, #0x20]  //Thread 1 error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 2, address = 0x16d0f3ff0)
    0x180d11ef4 <+8>:   stp    x24, x23, [sp, #0x30]

libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_release_:
    0x104e18d1c <+180>: bl     0x104e1a37c               ; bool swift::RefCounts<swift::SideTableRefCountBits>::doDecrement<(swift::PerformDeinit)1>(unsigned int)
->  0x104e18d20 <+184>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10. //Thread 1 error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 2, address = 0x16d0f3ff0)
    0x104e18d24 <+188>: ret
```

Does someone have idea how to resolve it?

Thanks!

Comment: What about using a debugger to find the issue?

Comment: With the debugger I see that the error occurs when assigning the value nil to self.head. Just before self.head has correct values, it becomes nil and the error is skipped before reaching the next instruction (within the removeAll function)

Comment: You should add that detail to your question.

Comment: OK. I have already edited it. Thanks!

Comment: I am confused by the code in the block `if let headNode =  self.head {` (in `enqueue_first()`).  It looks like `self.head` actually refers to the tail of the queue?!?

Comment: That method is to insert an item in the list ahead. For simplicity, you can remove that method

Comment: But `self.head` is not set to the new node.

Comment: OK. I see what you tell me. Thanks! But there is no problem

Comment: It's still not clear where "when assigning the value nil to self.head" is actually in your code.

Comment: In removeAll function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by changing the removeAll method of the LinkedList, for the following:

```
public func removeAll() {
    while head != nil {
        removeTail()
    }
} 


public func removeTail() {
    guard let tail = tail else {return}
    if let prev = tail.previous {
        prev.next = nil
        self.tail = prev
    } else {
        self.head = nil
        self.tail = nil
    }
    count -= 1


    if count < 0 { count = 0}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this error occurred when when I created a circular reference.

I created a Column object, and in the column initializer it counted out of how many columns were to be created. In order to count that list, that getter initialized an array of Columns.